# how make an insert images with id in mysql with jquery file upload plugin?

Tags: jquery, mysql, file-upload

I need to know how can I insert into mysql images and other id's to make FK with jquery file upload plugin... I already have the FK and work's.

I am really very noob with jquery file upload plugin... I already insert the form in my page but in this part I lost...I don't know where I need to insert my code like `$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO IMAGENES (id_paciente,imagenes,id_doctor) VALUES (:id_paciente,:imagenes,:id_doctor)');` to save the path of images in uploadhander.php...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you use any plugin at all?

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

upload_file.php:

```
<?php
$f = $_FILES['file'];

//move $f['tmp_name'] to some folder
//use PDO/MySqli for Mysql queries
?>
```

Comment: mmm I will try with uploadify...but I don't know if with uploadify can I insert in db the image(s) and also another data that is in the form.. thank you for your support!